# passport-github2 returns null in email field

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-github2

[passport-github2](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github) returns null in email field even when `{scope: ['user:email']}` was passed to `passport.authenticate('github',  {scope: ['user:email']  , session: false})(req, res, next)`

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking a bit into the source code, I found that there exists a function to get the email of user but for that, we need to pass the scope where we initialize our `GitHubStrategy`. I'm not sure why it's not documented anywhere!
To get it up and working I found that we need to do the following thing:

```js
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
      clientID: GITHUB_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GITHUB_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: GITHUB_OAUTH_CALLBACK,
      proxy: true,
      scope: ['user:email'] //This is all it takes to get emails
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, next) => {


// You get the profile object with emails array which can be accessed with 
// profile.emails[n].value

    }));
```

```js
//middleware
passport.authenticate('github',  {scope: ['user:email']  , session: false})(req, res, next)
```

It's really weird that it's not documented in their repo.

Note: Since for GitHub, you can't get the email address directly if it's set to private by the user, you need to call another endpoint([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/users#list-email-addresses-for-the-authenticated-user)).
It's written over here inside the source code: ([source](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github/blob/6c4e593ca4557ab841bae87378037a1379e35c26/lib/strategy.js#L24))

**PS: I'm still looking for a better way to access email without passing scope at two places.**